# iOS: UICollectionView animate height change

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, nslayoutconstraint, uiviewanimation

I have a simple `UICollectionView` in a view controller. I am animating the top constraint of the collection view via a button. On the FIRST button tap, the collection view cells are animating quite oddly. After subsequent taps the animation is smooth.

[image]

Method to animate:

```
@objc func animateAction() {
        
   UIView.animate(withDuration: 1) {
            
          self.animateUp.toggle()
          self.topConstraint.constant = self.animateUp ?  100 : self.view.bounds.height - 100
          self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
   }  
}
```

Edit: What actually needs to be built:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are animating the Top Constraint of your collection view, which changes its ***Height***.

Collection view's only render cells when needed.

So, at the start only one (or two) cells are created. Then as you change the Height, new cells are created and added. So, you see an "odd animation."

What you want to do is **NOT** set a bottom constraint for your collection view. Instead, set its Height constraint, and then change the Top constraint to "slide" it up and down:

[image]

I'm assuming you're using `UICollectionViewCompositionalLayout.list` with `appearance: .insetGrouped` ...

Here is a complete example to get that result:

```
struct MyCVData: Hashable {
    var name: String
}

class AnimCVViewController: UIViewController {
    
    var myCollectionView: UICollectionView!
    var dataSource: UICollectionViewDiffableDataSource<Section, MyCVData>!
    var cvDataList: [MyCVData] = []
    enum Section {
        case main
    }
    var snapshot: NSDiffableDataSourceSnapshot<Section, MyCVData>!
    
    var topConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!
    
    // when collection view is "Up" we want its
    //  Top to be 100-points from the Top of the view (safe area)
    var topPosition: CGFloat = 100
    
    // when collection view is "Down" we want its
    //  Top to be 80-points from the Bottom of the view (safe area)
    var bottomPosition: CGFloat = 80
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        // so we have a title if we're in a navigation controller
        self.navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(true, animated: false)
        view.backgroundColor = UIColor(white: 0.9, alpha: 1.0)
        
        configureCollectionView()
        buildData()
        
        // create an Animate button
        let btn = UIButton()
        btn.backgroundColor = .yellow
        btn.setTitle("Animate", for: [])
        btn.setTitleColor(.black, for: .normal)
        btn.setTitleColor(.lightGray, for: .highlighted)

        btn.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        myCollectionView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        
        view.addSubview(btn)
        view.addSubview(myCollectionView)
        
        let g = view.safeAreaLayoutGuide

        // start with the collection view "Down"
        topConstraint = myCollectionView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.bottomAnchor, constant: -bottomPosition)
        
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            
            // constrain the button at the Top, 200-pts width, centered horizontally
            btn.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.topAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            btn.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 200.0),
            btn.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.centerXAnchor),

            // button Height 10-points less than our collection view's Top Position
            btn.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: topPosition - 10.0),

            // activate top constraint
            topConstraint,

            // collection view Height should be the Height of the view (safe area)
            //  minus the Top Position
            myCollectionView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.heightAnchor, constant: -topPosition),
            
            // let's use 40-points leading and trailing
            myCollectionView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.leadingAnchor, constant: 40.0),
            myCollectionView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.trailingAnchor, constant: -40.0),

        ])
        
        // add an action for the button
        btn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(animateAction), for: .touchUpInside)
    }
    
    @objc func animateAction() {
        // if the topConstraint constant is -bottomPosition, that means it is "Down"
        //  so, if it's "Down"
        //      animate it so its Top is its own Height from the Bottom
        //  otherwise
        //      animate it so its Top is at bottomPosition
        topConstraint.constant = topConstraint.constant == -bottomPosition ? -myCollectionView.frame.height : -bottomPosition
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 1.0, animations: {
            self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
        })
    }

    func configureCollectionView() {
        
        var layoutConfig = UICollectionLayoutListConfiguration(appearance: .insetGrouped)
        
        layoutConfig.backgroundColor = .red
        
        let listLayout = UICollectionViewCompositionalLayout.list(using: layoutConfig)
        
        myCollectionView = UICollectionView(frame: .zero, collectionViewLayout: listLayout)
        
        let cellRegistration = UICollectionView.CellRegistration<UICollectionViewListCell, MyCVData> { (cell, indexPath, item) in
            
            var content = UIListContentConfiguration.cell()
            content.text = item.name
            content.textProperties.font.withSize(8.0)
            content.textProperties.font = UIFont.preferredFont(forTextStyle: .body)
            content.textProperties.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = false
            cell.contentConfiguration = content
        }
        
        dataSource = UICollectionViewDiffableDataSource<Section, MyCVData>(collectionView: myCollectionView) {
            (collectionView: UICollectionView, indexPath: IndexPath, identifier: MyCVData) -> UICollectionViewCell? in
            
            // Dequeue reusable cell using cell registration (Reuse identifier no longer needed)
            let cell = collectionView.dequeueConfiguredReusableCell(using: cellRegistration,
                                                                    for: indexPath,
                                                                    item: identifier)
            
            return cell
        }
        
    }
    
    func buildData() {
        // create 20 data items ("Cell: 1" / "Cell: 2" / "Cell: 3" / etc...)
        for i in 0..<20 {
            let d = MyCVData(name: "Cell: \(i)")
            cvDataList.append(d)
        }
        
        // Create a snapshot that define the current state of data source's data
        self.snapshot = NSDiffableDataSourceSnapshot<Section, MyCVData>()
        self.snapshot.appendSections([.main])
        self.snapshot.appendItems(cvDataList, toSection: .main)
        
        // Display data in the collection view by applying the snapshot to data source
        self.dataSource.apply(self.snapshot, animatingDifferences: false)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. It's working! But is there any way to animate the height with the collection view? I am building a scrollable bottom sheet for iOS 14. The collection view will be a part of the bottom sheet. I was experimenting with UISheetPresentationController (iOS 15) and it looks like the height of the view controller is changed.

Comment: @iqra - you would need to show the code you're using for your "bottom sheet"

Answer (score 0):

I faced this problem, here is what helped me. I needed to add these lines at the end of `collectionView(_:cellForItemAt:)`:

```
UIView.performWithoutAnimation {
    cell.layoutIfNeeded()
}
return cell
```